# ProfileBase.GetProperty() does not work on a new thread

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does this code not work if called within a new thread? The error returned is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the

```
return pb.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
```

this works

```
GetFullName(m);
```

while this doesnt

```
Thread t = new Thread(GetFullName);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();

public string GetFullName(string username)
{
    ProfileBase pb = ProfileBase.Create(username);
    return pb.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is because the HttpContext.Current is not available in the new thread (which is to be expected).

I recommend that you extract the necessary data on your "main thread" (the one that is serving the request) and pass it manually to the new thread.

Edit: If you want to transfer the HttpContext, it works like this:

```
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

Thread t = new Thread((string username) => {
    HttpContext.Current = ctx;
    GetFullName(userName);
});
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();

public string GetFullName(string username)
{
    ProfileBase pb = ProfileBase.Create(username);
    return pb.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
}
```

Comment: is there no way to allow HttpContext.Current to be available on the new thread?

Comment: There are two: You can either use the setter of HttpContext.Current and set it in manually, or you can transfer the LogicalCallContext (HttpContext.Current comes from that). I have no idea how I'd do the latter.

Comment: I think ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem will transfer the execution context. You could try that instead of a new thread.

Comment: what do you mean by use the setter of HttpContext.Current and set it in manually? How would I do that?

Comment: HttpContext.Current = ctx; ;-) You can set it to whatever value you want.

Comment: Yes. Copy the existing HttpContext from your request's thread over to the new thread. You need to save it in a new variable before you start the thread.

Comment: can you please provide an example. I cannot seem to make it work